# Wpf Font Style Not Working in RunTime and don't show correct view of my font in Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, resources, wpf-style

I using a **separate project** for my styles a and i have some line of codes like this in it:

```
<ResourceDictionary
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >

    <Style x:Key="NazaninFont"  TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Extra/Fonts/#IRNazanin"/>
    </Style>

    ......

</ResourceDictionary>
```

My another styles (like control effects and...) work well when i use my style key in the element like this:

```
Style="{ms:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=MyStyleKey}"
```

But When i use the following code in my **Lable** element

```
<Label Style="{ms:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=NazaninFont}" x:Name="LabelRemainingSec" Content="{Binding RemainingSec}"/>
```

I have:

- In Design Time >> The `FontFamily` is set on **IRNazanin** on the properties panel but **have not correct font view in the designer**!

BUT

- In Run Time >> The `FontFamily` is set on **Tahoma** (Window font)

---

Also i tested this way:

I added a style base on my font styles in the separate project, in top of my Window, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="NazaninFont" BasedOn="{ms:MyStyleRef ResourceKey=NazaninFont}" TargetType="Label"/>
```

Then i use it in my Lable normaly:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource NazaninFont}" x:Name="LabelRemainingSec" Content="{Binding RemainingSec}"/>
```

Result is same as previous way:

In the `Design Time` in the `FontFamily` is on **IRNazanin** and have not correct font view in XAML designer! And in `Run Time` it is on **Tahoma**

What do you think about my problem? I think think my styles can not give the font path to the `Label` control correctly.

Comment: yes i installed it, if i type it in the font family and press enter then i see correct view of the font but when it set by style : did not show correct view

Comment: Yes it work fine... but i want use this font in a separate project as resource of my application in a style way.

Comment: But i want read the font from my resource not from windows font folder!

Comment: Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.110).aspx).  One this worth mentioning is this: `Absolute URI using the pack: notation: WPF applications do not allow you to create a FontFamily object programmatically using "pack:" as part of the absolute uniform resource identifier (URI) reference to a font. For example, "pack://application:,,,/resources/#Pericles Light" is an invalid font reference.`

Comment: Thanks @Netscape, but what is the correct way to use fonts inside a resource project?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be what you are after, but I'll take a guess that it is :p

You can define a FontFamily Resource in your resource dictionary, or where ever you want really. Take note of how I have defined it in Window.Resources.

I have included the physical font file in my project inside a folder called 'fonts' (no need for packing), and referenced it using the **Font name:** value. This is found by double clicking the font file (where it displays a whole heap of demo text and the option to install). **You do not use the name of the file itself, you use the Font name: value when referencing**. Also, don't forget the # at the start of any font reference! :)

Then, call it like you would any other resource for font family

Both the labels will be a different font. Please note that the font change won't be visible during design time unfortunately, only during runtime.

Working code as a demonstration:

```
<Window x:Class="Tinker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="MyFont">fonts/#Roboto Thin</FontFamily> 
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label FontSize="36" Content="Helloooooo World!"/>
        <Label FontSize="36" FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFont}" Content="Helloooooo World!"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```